# I cannot send selected value to test.html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I cannot send selected value to test.html.
I wrote codes

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <select id="mainDD" data-placeholder="Choose" class="chzn-select" style="width:600px;" name="main">
    {% for i in json_data.items.values %}
            <option value="{{forloop.counter}}">{{ i }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
    </select>

    {% for key, values in preprocessed %}
    <select name="type" id=type{{forloop.counter}}>
    {% for counter, value in values %}
        <option value="{{forloop.counter}}">{{ value }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
    </select>
    {% endfor %}
    </form>

  <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#mainDD').on('change', function() {
              var thisType = "type" + $(this).val();
              for(i=1; i<6; i++) {
                  var thisId = "type" + i;
                  if(thisType !== thisId) {
                    $("#"+thisId).hide();
                  }
                  else {
                    $("#"+thisId).show();
                  }
              }

            }).trigger('change');

        });


  </script>

     <form id="postform" action="app/test_view" method="GET">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <input type="submit" value="SEND">
     </form>
     <script type="text/javascript">
        var key = $('select[name="main"] option:selected').text();
        var value = $('select[name="type"] option:selected').text();
        var array1 = [];
        var array2 =[];
          document.querySelector("input[type=submit]").onclick = e => {
           const test = window.open(`test_view?${key}=${value}`, "_blank");
          }

     </script>
```

But now test.html shows
[image]

I wrote test.html

```
<h2>RESULTS</h2>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      onload = () => {
        document.body.appendChild(
          document.createTextNode([...new URLSearchParams(location.search).entries()])
          );
      }

    </script>
```

I selected i(actually value is A) & value(actually value is a-1) in index.html so I wanna show in test.html like
[image]

These 2 selected buttons load json file like

```
  {
        "items": 
          {
            "---":"---",
            "A":"A",
            "B":"B",
         },
        "type1":
          {
            "---":"---",
            "a-1":"a-1",
            "a-2":"a-2",
         },
        "type2":
          {
            "---":"---",
            "b-1":"b-1",
            "b-2":"b-2",
         }
    }
```

How should I fix this?What should I write it?Is it garbled？or code error?

Comment: @ShadowFiend Which parts do you think?I replace val() in `var thisType = "type" + $(this).val();`,only 1 button is shown